# intellij idea version control can‘t work well

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

I generate some XXXmapper.java with mybatis-genarate. In intellij Local Changes Tab , I find that 21 files are changed.

[image]

However，When I check what files are changed ，I find that there is no changed. I use the command “show diff”，it show that “no differences”.

Is It a bug for intellij idea.

[image]

Comment: Could be line endings.  Did you view the diff in IntelliJ?

Comment: are the mapper files new or previously tracked?

Comment: What's the output of the command `git diff filename`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Good idea. When I chang the line endings to "LF", the version controle works well .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Line endings are changed, git on the command line will report the files a modified, so it is expected behavior.

If you are on Windows, you most likely have `git config core.autocrlf` set to `true` thus you will not be able to commit the line endings changes to the repository.

Here is the request to better handle such situations in IntelliJ.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-175120